# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Managed Object property

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm experiencing a problem on my current project.

The goal is to download a pdf file and display it in a UIPageViewController.
The user can scroll through the available pdfs via a UICollectionView which is served with data by a NSFetchedResultsController.

If the read button is triggered the Managed Object is passed to a ViewController, which
checks if a pdf is already downloaded or if it needs to be downloaded and then displays it.

This code is responsible for loading the new View Controller and pass the Managed Object to it.

```
- (IBAction)readNowButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:cell.tag inSection:0];
    EPaper *epaper = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (epaper) {

        DHEPaperLoadingViewController  *epaperLoadingViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"epaperLoadingController"];
        epaperLoadingViewController.epaper = epaper;
        epaperLoadingViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:epaperLoadingViewController animated:YES];
    }

}
```

This code is in the viewDidLoad method of the new View Controller and decides how to handle the data.

```
if (self.epaper.pdfData) {
        [self createPDFForData:self.epaper.pdfData];
        [self displayPDF];
    }
    else {
        [DHDownloadHelper downloadPDFWithRequest:[self createURLRequest]];

        __weak DHEPaperLoadingViewController *weakSelf = self;
        EPaper *currentEpaper = self.epaper;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:EPAPER_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = note.object;
            float progress = [[userInfo objectForKey:EPAPER_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS] floatValue];
            weakSelf.progressBar.progress = progress;
        }];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:EPAPER_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED_NOTIFICATION object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = note.object;
            NSData *data = [userInfo objectForKey:EPAPER_DOWNLOAD_DATA];
            currentEpaper.pdfData = data;


            [currentEpaper.managedObjectContext save:nil];
            [weakSelf createPDFForData:data];
            [weakSelf displayPDF];
        }];
    }
}
```

This works fine in most cases. However there a situations where EXC_BAD_ACCESS appears to happen on this line:

```
if (self.epaper.pdfData) //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

This error occurs under following conditions and can be reproduced:

- The read button has been triggered 3 times for the same item (It can be triggered once and it downloads correctly, it can be triggered
  again and it shows the pdf correctly without downloading it again but
  it crashes on the third time)
- One pdf was downloaded and displayed correctly and another item needs
  to be downloaded

To my knowledge EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when an object is already released,
but I have a strong pointer to it and checked if it responds to the property selector (which is does). I also made sure the code is executed on the main thread.

What else could cause this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
if (self.epaper && self.epaper.pdfData)
```

but I'm not sure if that would be hiding another issue.

Also are you removing yourself as an observer for those notifications? From the docs...

> You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

self.epaper is not nil. It's actually holding the reference to the managed object like it's supposed to.
The code passes the if (self.epaper) condition but crashes (in the aforementioned cases) when i try to access self.epaper.pdfData.


I forgot to remove myself but added it now. Still results in the same error. But thanks for the enlightenment!